# Unit tests are getting executed twice when performing mvn install

Tags: maven

Unit tests are getting executed twice.

When i am removing goal report and phase prepare-package from maven plugins in pom, test are getting executed once but then coverage are not getting generated in the console.

But when i am adding goal report and phase prepare-package from maven plugins in pom,i am getting coverage in the console but unit tests are getting executed twice.

I need to have goal report and phase prepare-package in  my pom in order to get coverage  but need to run test cases only once. What is the way to to get the test case executed only once with coverage as well.

```
<plugins>
        <!-- Configure maven-compiler-plugin to use the desired Java version -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Use build-helper-maven-plugin to add Scala source and test source
            directories -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/scala</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>add-test-source</id>
                    <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/test/scala</source>
                        </sources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- Use scala-maven-plugin for Scala support -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>net.alchim31.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>scala-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <!-- Need to specify this explicitly, otherwise plugin won't be called
                            when doing e.g. mvn compile -->
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <!-- disable surefire -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <configuration>
           <skipTests>true</skipTests>

         </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scoverage</groupId>
            <artifactId>scoverage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${scoverage.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <aggregate>true</aggregate>
                <highlighting>true</highlighting>
                <scalacPluginVersion>1.3.0</scalacPluginVersion>
                <minimumCoverage>30</minimumCoverage>
                <failOnMinimumCoverage>false</failOnMinimumCoverage>
            </configuration>

                            <executions>
                                <execution>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>report</goal> <!-- or integration-check -->
                                    </goals>
                                    <phase>prepare-package</phase> <!-- or any other phase -->

                              </execution>
                            </executions>

        </plugin>
        <!-- enable scalatest -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scalatest</groupId>
            <artifactId>scalatest-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>
                    -javaagent:"${settings.localRepository}"/org/aspectj/aspectjweaver/${aspectj.version}/aspectjweaver-${aspectj.version}.jar
                </argLine>

                <forkMode>once</forkMode>

                <reportsDirectory>${project.build.directory}/surefire-reports</reportsDirectory>
                <junitxml>.</junitxml>
                <filereports>WDF TestSuite.txt</filereports>
                <!-- The scalatest-maven-plugin seems broken for the spanScaleFactor,
                    so pass it via system property, instead -->
                <!-- <spanScaleFactor>${scalatest.span.scale.factor}</spanScaleFactor> -->
                <systemProperties>
                    <spanScaleFactor>${scalatest.span.scale.factor}</spanScaleFactor>
                </systemProperties>

            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>test</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>enter code here
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. Add following line in 'scoverage-maven-plugin' plugin's 'configuration' section.

   ```
   <additionalForkedProjectProperties>skipTests=false</additionalForkedProjectProperties>
   ```
2. Set following property in your root pom.xml

   ```
   <properties>
        <!--  Add other properties here... -->

        <!--  skipTests is set to 'true' here to avoid duplicate runs of all test cases. It's set to false in scoverage-maven-plugin below. -->
        <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </properties>
   ```